# Setting OnTouchListener for a view inside Viewpager prevents viewpager from scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

I have a textview inside a viewpager.I have added a functionality to text view, such that user can hold the textview to hide, and appear after releasing the touch.

```
autoResizeTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                return true;    // <- set to true
            }
        });

     autoResizeTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {

                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                 }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

But this disabled viewpager's scrolling. How can I disable touch listener for textview while viewpager is scrolling?

I have set textview's height and width to fillparent btw.

Comment: you have to intercept the touch and do i

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the listener you can remove it from the TextView or set a boolean flag that makes it ignore all events. The [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface should allow you to determine the scroll state of the ViewPager using onPageScrollStateChanged() - if the state isn't SCROLL_IDLE, you should disable the TextView listener.